# Weird issue selecting a radio button

Tags: jquery, html, button, radio-button

I seem to be having an issue selecting a radio button using jQuery. I put together a [simple Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz7vr/) to demonstrate the issue. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="divRadioButtons">
    <div style="width: 600px; margin: 5px auto;">
        <div style="display: inline"><input type="radio" name="activeStatus" value="Active" id="rbActiveActive" checked="checked">Active</div>&nbsp;
        <div style="display: inline"><input type="radio" name="activeStatus" value="Inactive" id="rbActiveInactive">Inactive</div>&nbsp;
        <div style="display: inline"><input type="radio" name="activeStatus" value="ComingSoon" id="rbActiveComingSoon">Coming Soon</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-table">
    <input type="button" value="Active" id="btnActive" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-table">
    <input type="button" value="Inactive" id="btnInactive" />
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    Reset();

    $('#btnActive').click(function() {
        Reset();
        $('#rbActiveActive').attr('checked', true);
        $('#rbActiveInactive').attr('checked', false);
        $('#rbActiveComingSoon').attr('checked', false);
        $('#divRadioButtons').show();

    });

    $('#btnInactive').click(function() {
        Reset();
        $('#rbActiveActive').attr('checked', false);
        $('#rbActiveInactive').attr('checked', true);
        $('#rbActiveComingSoon').attr('checked', false);
        $('#divRadioButtons').show();
    });
});

function Reset()
{
    $('#divRadioButtons').hide();
    $('#rbActiveActive').attr('checked', false);
    $('#rbActiveInactive').attr('checked', false);
    $('#rbActiveComingSoon').attr('checked', false);
}
```

When I click on the `Active` button, I want the active radio button to be checked. When I click on the `Inactive` button, I want the Inactive radio button to be checked.

The issue is really weird because check this out. If I run my fiddle and click the `Inactive` button, it works. But if I click the `Inactive` button a second time (or third, or fourth time), it deselects it and never works again. If I run my fiddle and select the `Active` button, it never works, even though the button code is identical!

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I seem to be tearing my hair out at this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Fz7vr/1/)**

As the docs for [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) states:

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method.

and...

> the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is
>   that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute
>   actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used
>   only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute
>   value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the
>   checked property does.

Comment: Thank you! This does seem to work properly now. Seems like such a simple problem I was having.